# Find similarity ratio between images [Best matching image]

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to find the ratio of similarity between source and list of images which outputs best matching image to the user. Input image can be of any shape and my program should find the best matching images. I am very new to OpenCV but trying to learn it for my implementation. I tried many tutorials and tried finding some samples but none of those fulfill my requirements. The sample images are like below.
[image]

I tried following approaches:

1. Comparing Histogram  => Not best approach for my implementation
2. Template Matching    => Images can be of different shape and size.
3. Feature Matching     => Did not find any best tutorial that can differentiate similarities.

Other approach I tried are SIFT, SURF and FAST but both work for point data not for shape data. I am implementing this using openCV for C++.

Comment: I just want to know, are your images will always be binary ? and shape will be ideal like above ?

Comment: have to make binary... since they are all shape matching so wont be a problem I guess...

Comment: I think instead of using an unsupervised approach you should do something like, counting the circles, squares, rectangles, triangles, etc. because, it is much easier for this context. After you count the shapes, you can also extract information from shapes, like their size, their orientation, etc. and with that information you can find similarity based on the similarity metric you defined.

Comment: extract contour and use cv::matchShapes. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#matchshapes Just out of interest: Would you saye that first row nr 3 and first row number 5 are similar or not? the term "similarity" is very ambiguous and unclear, so depending on YOUR definition of similarity, you have to choose or design your algorithm.

Comment: Hough Transform can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try to use signatures of the shape,signatures are nothing but gives you information of boundry of the peticular shape.

Code for signature extraction is:

```
            function sig = signature(bw,prec)
            boundry = bwboundaries(bw);

            xy = boundry{1};

            x = xy(:,1);
            y = xy(:,2);

            len = length(x);
            res = (len/prec);

            re = rem(res,2);

            if re
                res = ceil(res);
            end

            indexes = 1:res:len;

            xnew = x(indexes);
            ynew = y(indexes);

            cx = round(mean(xnew));
            cy = round(mean(ynew));

            xn = abs(xnew-cx);
            yn = abs(ynew-cy);

            sig = (xn.^2+yn.^2);
            sig = sig/max(sig);
```

and example of how to use above function is:

```
            clc
            clear all
            close all

            path = 'E:\GoogleDrive\Mathworks\irisDEt\shapes';
            im1 = imread([path,'\3.png']);
            gray1 = ((im1));

            scales = [1,2,3,4];
            gray1 = im2bw(gray1);

            for i = 1:length(scales)
                im = imresize(gray1,scales(i));
                sig = signature(im,25);

                figure,plot(sig)
                fra = getframe();
                image = frame2im(fra);
                imwrite(image,['E:\GoogleDrive\Mathworks\irisDEt\shapes\',num2str(i),'.png'])
            end
```

In above example I am selecting a shape and change the size of the shape using `imresize` function and controlling length of signature of the shape by precision.

Signature of a shape

[image]

in different sizes is as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

All above signatures are generated by the code given above.

Comment: thanks miki for edit.... i was in hurry that time so i just write all things and submitted the answer.